# Salesforce field updated mysteriously

Tags: triggers, workflow, salesforce, schedule

There is a boolean field called ready to process, which is for some special cases that we need to be manually check first before it's processed. recently we have experienced very weird behaviour. as when someone changed the field value. it will change back to the other value itself after 1-2 minutes. as I am tracking the history of this field, I can see that the change action was taken by whoever changed the value 1-2 minutes ago.

I have checked the trigger on that object, relevant schedule jobs and all workflow rules work on that field.But I can't find anything could cause this.

So my question is: except trigger, schedule job and workflow rule, what could change the value of a field automatically and act as a person instead of the system robot.

Thanks

Lee

Comment: take a look of this https://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/workflow_field_update_considerations.htm

Answer (score 0):

Have you check if there is any batch APEX running that touches it?  Assuming that the "ready to process" field gets picked up by some process that waits for the flag to be true.  Does this process perhaps update the field back to it's not ready state afterwords?